# Adding an Image inside tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I have a quick question regarding LaTeX's ability to add a small image inside a `tcolorbox`. What I am trying to accomplish is an entire line with a red color fill and left aligned white text and an image at the end of the line (The image is a rectangular with identical height as the line. Here is the code which I would like to add an image to.

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[
      breakable,
      left=0pt,
      right=0pt,
      top=8pt,
      bottom=8pt,
      colback=red,
      colframe=red,
      width=\textwidth, 
      enlarge left by=0mm,
      boxsep=5pt,
      arc=0pt,
      outer arc=0pt,
    ]
    \Large
    \textbf{\textcolor{white}{Left Aligned Text} }
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Currently when I add an `\includegraphics` command it ruins the dimensions of the colorbox above.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Using `\smash{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{demo}}` will add it without distorting the box.  You may need a `\raisebox` to vertically get it where you want.

Answer (score 5):

Based on my comment, I `\smash`ed the `\includegraphics` and used a `\raisebox` to center it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
%      breakable,
      left=0pt,
      right=0pt,
      top=8pt,
      bottom=8pt,
      colback=red,
      colframe=red,
      width=\textwidth, 
      enlarge left by=0mm,
      boxsep=5pt,
      arc=0pt,
      outer arc=0pt,
    ]
    \Large
    \textbf{\textcolor{white}{Left Aligned Text}
  \hfill\smash{\raisebox{-11pt}{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{demo}}} 
}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's what worked for me, assuming that you wanted the image to be as high as the **text** in the line, not as high as the colored line itself.

```
\textbf{\textcolor{white}{Left Aligned Text}
  \newlength{\somelength}
  \settoheight{\somelength}{\hbox{A}}\hfill
  \includegraphics[height=\somelength]{/home/nickie/lib/images/picsig.jpg}}
```

The `A` inside the `\hbox` serves the purpose of finding the height of the text and setting `\somelength` to its value.  Then, this length is used as the height of the picture.

[image: result]

Notice that I had to remove `breakable` and `outer arc` from my source code, as I think I have an older `tcolorbox`.  So, if what you get is slightly different, this may be reasonable.

If I'm wrong and you wanted the image to be bigger than the text's height, then you need something like `\smash` that Steven suggested (in his comment and answer) but you'll have to place it yourself where you want it.