# Alignment of image in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

Many times we see in books, some significant points, some tips and tricks are put in an attractive box with an image in it (usually the text will be in italics). I would like to achieve the same effect. I have referred this link : [Adding an Image inside tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169418/adding-an-image-inside-tcolorbox). And this is what I have achieved :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
%      breakable,
      left=0pt,
      right=0pt,
      top=8pt,
      bottom=8pt,
      colback=white,
      colframe=red,
      width=\textwidth,
      enlarge left by=0mm,
      boxsep=5pt,
      arc=4pt,
      outer arc=4pt,
    ]
    \Large
  \smash{\raisebox{-11pt}{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{colorbox}}}\hfill
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Now, my question is, How to align that image and add a text not at the center but as a paragraph.

What I want to achieve is :

[image]

Comment: As an alternative to `tcolorbox`, [`bclogo`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bclogo) was designed to make this kind of boxes: framed and colorfull boxes with a little logo on them.

Comment: Can you show me a sample MWE @Ignasi

Comment: Yes, but because is not what you want I've added [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16225/1952)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adjust the settings according to your needs:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
  enhanced,
  left=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  top=8pt,
  bottom=8pt,
  colback=white,
  colframe=red,
  width=\textwidth,
  enlarge left by=0mm,
  boxsep=5pt,
  fontupper=\itshape\small,
  arc=4pt,
  outer arc=4pt,
  leftupper=1.5cm,
  overlay={
    \node[anchor=west] 
      at ([xshift=10pt] $ (frame.north west)!0.5!(frame.south west) $ )
       {\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{example-image-a}};}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[4]
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with a different vertical alignment for the image:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
  enhanced,
  left=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  top=8pt,
  bottom=8pt,
  colback=white,
  colframe=red,
  width=\textwidth,
  enlarge left by=0mm,
  boxsep=5pt,
  fontupper=\itshape\small,
  arc=4pt,
  outer arc=4pt,
  leftupper=1.5cm,
  overlay={
    \node[anchor=north west] 
      at ([xshift=10pt,yshift=-.65\baselineskip]frame.north west)
       {\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{example-image-a}};}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[4]
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! Note to self: option ``enhanced`` very much needed to support ``\includegraphics`` inside ``overlay=`` option, in my experience.

Comment: If your box has a title, and you want to centre align the image to the content of the box, you will have to use `interior.north west)!0.5!(interior.south west)` instead. I know this isn't exactly what the OP asked but thought it would be useful :)