# Vertical alignment in a tcolorbox including an image

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm facing an issue i can't solve by my own : i'm trying to make a tcolorbox with an image and a text inside. I would like to change the text alignment to center it

mwe :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[skins,theorems]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mwe}


\newtcbox{\important}{enhanced,on line,
  colframe=red,colback=red!5!white, box align=center,
  boxrule=0.5pt,arc=4pt,boxsep=0pt,left=6pt,right=6pt,top=6pt,bottom=6pt}
  
\newcommand{\appel}{\begin{center} \important{\includegraphics[scale=0.07]{image} Here you write the text }\end{center}}
    
  
\begin{document}

\appel

\end{document}
```

It's probably easy but i can't figure how to change it -_-
I've probably tried some stupid things in my /newtcbox lol

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181090/alignment-of-image-in-tcolorbox

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With thanks to @GonzaloMedina at

[Alignment of image in tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181090/alignment-of-image-in-tcolorbox)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{ enhanced,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    top=8pt,
    bottom=8pt,
    colback=red!5,
    colframe=red,
    width=\textwidth,
    enlarge left by=0mm,
    boxsep=5pt,
    fontupper=\itshape\small,
    arc=4pt,
    outer arc=4pt,
    leftupper=1.5cm,
    overlay={
        \node[anchor=west] 
        at ([xshift=10pt] $ (frame.north west)!0.5!(frame.south west) $ )
        {\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{example-image-a}};}
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{mybox}
    Add some text here in the center
    \end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be nice to comment that you took the code from [this answer from Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/181100/1952)

Comment: Thanks. I saw this one but i didn't created with a newtcolorbox but with newtcbox , however i used it to make my example working, thanks !